# Subtract multiple values from row of numpy 2D-array at the same time, using indices

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, indexing

I have a 2D `numpy` array `f`, for example:

```
f = np.array(
   [
    [0,0,0],
    [0,0,0],
    [0,0,0]
   ]
)
```

and another 2D array `q`, for example:

```
q = np.array(
   [
    [1,1,1],
    [1,1,1],
    [2,2,2],
    [3,3,3]
   ]
)
```

Each row in `q` should be added to a certain row in `f`, and I only have a list `l` of indices of rows in `f`, to which each row in `q` should be added. The length of `l` is equal to the number of rows in `q`. For example:

```
l = [0,2,0,0]
```

That means I want to do something like this:

```
f[l] += q
```

which should transform `f` into:

```
[
 [6,6,6],
 [0,0,0],
 [1,1,1]
]
```

i.e. I'm expecting it to do this:

```
f[0] += q[0]
f[2] += q[1]
f[0] += q[2]
f[0] += q[3]
```

but when some indices are repeated in `l` (index `0` in this example), it only adds the row in `q` that corresponds to the last repeated index in `l`. So instead, I get:

```
[
 [3,3,3],
 [0,0,0],
 [1,1,1]
]
```

That means it's doing this:

```
f[2] += q[1]
f[0] += q[3]
```

How can I add multiple rows in `q` to the same row in `f`, just having the list `l`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try [`np.add.at`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.ufunc.at.html): `np.add.at(f, l, q)`